# Filter and Aggregate a column not in the group by clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table. I'm using mysql-5.7. Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dc909da120f2a346366ae952e40192d5)

```
select * from report;
+----+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------+------+-------------------+
| id | date_hour           | speed   | name | nor  | validation | p_i  | speed_performance |
+----+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------+------+-------------------+
|  1 | 2018-02-03 13:23:00 |   -12.3 | SYN  |   10 | 1          | 3    | 4                 |
|  2 | 2018-02-03 11:23:00 |   -6.36 | SYN  |   13 | 0          | 4    | 5                 |
|  3 | 2018-02-03 01:23:00 |  -26.36 | SYN  |   24 | 0          | 2    | 4                 |
|  4 | 2020-04-06 21:23:00 | -156.36 | SYN  |   16 | 1          | 3    | 6                 |
|  5 | 2020-04-06 03:23:00 |  -36.36 | YRT  |  136 | 0          | 2    | 5                 |
|  6 | 2020-04-06 12:23:00 |  -16.36 | SYN  |   13 | 1          | 4    | 4                 |
+----+---------------------+---------+------+------+------------+------+-------------------+
```

I would like to `group by` `date_hour` such that after `12:00:00`, it counts as the next day. The `p_i` column should be averaged based on this condition: take `average` of `p_i` where `validation` is 1 and `p_i` is non-zero. The values should be averaged based on the new version of `date_hour`. Additionally, another column (`nor`) is averaged without such a condition.

The output should look like this

```
+------+------------+----------+------+
| name | date_hr    | avg(nor) | p_i  |
+------+------------+----------+------+
| SYN  | 2018-02-03 |     18.5 | NULL |
| SYN  | 2018-02-04 |       10 |    3 |
| SYN  | 2020-04-07 |     14.5 |  3.5 |
| YRT  | 2020-04-06 |      136 | NULL |
+------+------------+----------+------+
```

I tried the following query. I had to disable `only_full_group_by` to get it to work.:

```
select name, 
case when time(date_hour) > '12:00:00' 
then date(date_hour) + interval 1 day 
else date(date_hour) end as date_hr, 
avg(nor), 
case when validation = 1 and p_i > 0 then avg(p_i) else null end as p_i 
from report group by name, date_hr;

+------+------------+----------+------+
| name | date_hr    | avg(nor) | p_i  |
+------+------------+----------+------+
| SYN  | 2018-02-03 |     18.5 |    3 |
| SYN  | 2018-02-04 |       10 | NULL |
| SYN  | 2020-04-07 |     14.5 | NULL |
| YRT  | 2020-04-06 |      136 |    2 |
+------+------------+----------+------+
```

Comment: I don't see how I can improve it. Are you talking about the 2 superfluous columns? I've repositioned the fiddle link for greater visibility.

Comment: Why not just add 12 hours to your GROUP BY?

Comment: I think I'm doing the same thing in effect using `group by date_hr`?

Comment: Maybe, but the CASEs would become redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select max(name) name,
       date(date_add(date_hour, interval 12 hour)) date,
       avg(nor) avg_nor,
       avg(case when validation = '1' and p_i <> 0 then p_i end) avg_p_i 
from report
group by date
```

I used the aggregate function `max()` to return the column `name`, but you can also use `min()` or `any_value()`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b9021f501838f42df650fd2ee4403bc5).
Results:

```
> name | date       | avg_nor | avg_p_i
> :--- | :--------- | ------: | ------:
> SYN  | 2018-02-03 |    18.5 |    null
> SYN  | 2018-02-04 |      10 |       3
> YRT  | 2020-04-06 |     136 |    null
> SYN  | 2020-04-07 |    14.5 |     3.5
```